# How to print all possibilities of nested lists in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Here is my list:

```
pos = [['det'], ['noun', 'adj'], ['noun'], ['vb'], ['det'], ['vb', 'noun', 'adj']]
```

Or

```
pos = ['det', ['noun', 'adj'], 'noun', 'vb', 'det', ['vb', 'noun', 'adj']]
```

I'm trying to print all the combinations:

```
det noun noun vb det vb
det adj noun vb det vb
det noun noun vb det noun
det adj noun vb det noun
det noun noun vb det adj
det adj noun vb det adj
```

Should I use recursive function? I tried with no result.

Itertools (permutations, product, combinations) doesn't help me.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `itertools.product()` actually *is* what you are looking for:

```
pos = [['det'], ['noun', 'adj'], ['noun'],
       ['vb'], ['det'], ['vb', 'noun', 'adj']]
for x in itertools.product(*pos):
    print " ".join(x)
```

prints

```
det noun noun vb det vb
det noun noun vb det noun
det noun noun vb det adj
det adj noun vb det vb
det adj noun vb det noun
det adj noun vb det adj
```

Comment: You are right, it does work ! I don't know why i didn't get this result when i tried. Anyway, thanks a lot !

Comment: I have the problem, when having string numbers,  which are 2 digits it does not work. It also splits the digits, what I do not want. Any idea how to solve this behavior?

Comment: @eljobso From your comment, I can't understand what exactly you are doing and what the problem is.  I suggest asking a new question describing your problem.  Add your code to the question, explain the expected output and show the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

'itertools' does help:

```
for i in itertools.product(*pos): print i
('det', 'noun', 'noun', 'vb', 'det', 'vb')
('det', 'noun', 'noun', 'vb', 'det', 'noun')
('det', 'noun', 'noun', 'vb', 'det', 'adj')
('det', 'adj', 'noun', 'vb', 'det', 'vb')
('det', 'adj', 'noun', 'vb', 'det', 'noun')
('det', 'adj', 'noun', 'vb', 'det', 'adj')
```